# Five Plate Capacitor - How to calculate?

Tags: capacitor

I'm taking an electrical engineering course as part of my Bachelor's degree, and sadly our tutorials don't seem very well laid out. We've been given the following capacitor and asked to calculate capacitance and charge.

I have the formulas but can't figure out from the image if the capacitors are in series or parallel. How can I approach the problem?

[image: Five plate capacitor]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Given I can't figure out if the capacitor can be redrawn as a set in series or in parallel, I don't know which set of formulas to use. My gut says parallel, if only because series would be a very easy calculation, but otherwise, I don't know how to start.

Comment: Can you redraw this as a schematic with conventional lumped capacitors rather than the physical arrangement of plates and dielectric?

Comment: I assume so, but I don't know how to in this instance.

Comment: I am 1st year on uni and I think I have solution :)

Comment: I have zero electrical engineering background. This is supposed to be an introductory course, which I'm either finding very hard or is badly structured. I have no problem with Differential Equations but this confuses me

Comment: Draw four, unconnected capacitors on a paper. Then try to draw connections that would be equivalent as in your original diagram. You have your answer.

Comment: @dim has hit the nail on the head except there are only 4 capacitors. Uh, maybe he edited it to 4 just now LOL.

Comment: Thanks, I think that helped. From that I think they're all in parallel. Is that right? The arrangement really confused me. They sort of face into each other, right? With the negative sides together?

Comment: They are in parallel with inner plates forming a capacitor on either side.

Comment: Thank you! Given the required knowledge for this course is supposed to be zero I'm spending a lot of time researching answers on the web

Comment: Would it also mean that the charges on the plates aren't equal? So that the absolute charges on 2,3,4 are bigger than 1 & 5?

Comment: It's very nice you have tutorials to blame. Did you understand the chapter about capacitance, and previous ones, about potentials and fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clear enough, even as far as the charges are concerned, isn't it?

[image]

Comment: Excellent schematic diagramm with all useful information. The use of the letters A and B as part pin labels clearly shows that both schemes are equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

I have just finished electrostatics at my uni.

The electrical field on a simple capacitor is observed. It can be concluded that the electrical field has a value and is not 0.
[image: simple capacitor electrical fields]

The same concept is applied to your schematic.
[image: step1]

It is therefore simplified.

[image: step2]

[image: step3]

There is no electrical field between the inner plates. I think it is same as connecting the both plates of the first capacitor to positive side. 
Is this correct?

Comment: Please, when you post images try to scale them down and crop them to save us from downloading huge quantities of useless bits and slowing down browsing this post to a crawl! There are lots of free/open source image processing programs out there (e.g. FastStone Image Viewer, IrfanView, TheGimp): get one and save our bandwidth (your scribbled corrections in your drawings, your wooden ruler or part of your desktop are NOT relevant at all)!!!

Comment: You can't simplify it like that. There are most definitely fields in between all of the plates.

Comment: I don't get it.  But more importantly, does OP get it?